# How to use geocoding offline in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Enter place name in textformField and submit then camera position is move to this location and draw line between device current location to destination and also show the distance between them how can it done. But all these things is completely offline.

void _onSubmitLocation() async {
final String enteredLocation = locationName.text;

```
if (enteredLocation.isNotEmpty) {
  try {
    List<geocoding.Location> locations =
        await geocoding.locationFromAddress(enteredLocation);

    if (locations.isNotEmpty) {
      // Assuming the first location returned is the most relevant one
      final geocoding.Location firstLocation = locations.first;
      final LatLng newLocation =
          LatLng(firstLocation.latitude!, firstLocation.longitude!);

      mapController?.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(
        newLocation,
        14, // You can adjust the zoom level as needed
      ));
    } else {
      // Handle case when no locations are found for the entered address
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: const Text("Location not found"),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
      ));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle any errors that may occur during geocoding
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: const Text("Error finding location"),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
    ));
  }
}
```

}

these code work only in online but i need offline.
how to make these code for offline use.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: You can't use Geocoding offline.

Long Answer: According to the docs:

> This plugin uses the free Geocoding services provided by the iOS and Android platforms. This means that there are restrictions to their use.

In order for Google and Apple to track and limit your usage. You will need to have an internet connection when the API is called.

Comment: Then how to store these data in local database an use when system is offline anyone provide code??

Comment: I want to search location and navigate but offline any possible way to do it??

Comment: you can try this package https://pub.dev/packages/mapsforge_flutter